# The remote address when opening the website through playwright is different from the remote address when opening the website manually

Tags: remote-access, playwright

a. This is the remote address I see when opening the webpage manually
[image]

b. remote address I see when opening the webpage through playwright
[image]

Due to the variance in the remote address my webpage is not launching from playwright. Can you please advice how to get the same remote address when launching the site from playwright

I am going through the playwright documentation to find the solution. I am expecting to have a remote address which is similar to the remote address when I launch the site manually. I believe the issue will be resolved after that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the site doesn't load for you in Playwright - it would be easier if you included your code - but the IP address is possibly not the issue.

It looks to me like the site at that IP address might just be running on a CDN or otherwise load balanced and it just so happens that your different browsers are being sent to different locations, possibly due to small differences e.g. cookies stored in your normal browser.

If I enter the website's URL it loads for me successfully, but from a different IP again.